# Can't get data when change Raw Query to Query Builder in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a working raw query like this:

```
$sql = DB::select("SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst WHERE ID_ LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR PROC_INST_ID_ LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR PROC_DEF_ID_ COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR START_TIME_ LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR END_TIME_ LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR DURATION_ LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR START_USER_ID_ COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR START_ACT_ID_ COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR END_ACT_ID_ COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci LIKE '%$searchValue%' 
                                                        OR SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ LIKE '%$searchValue%'");
```

But if I use this, I can't use paginate function in my query. So I decided to change it into Query Builder like this:

```
$sql = DB::table('act_hi_procinst')
                ->where('ID_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('PROC_INST_ID_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('PROC_DEF_ID_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('START_TIME_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('END_TIME_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('DURATION_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('START_USER_ID_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('START_ACT_ID_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('END_ACT_ID_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->orWhere('SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')
                ->get();
```

And when I run this, it return no data. I use getQueryLog() and see this:

> array:1 [▼
>     0 => array:3 [▼
>       "query" => "select * from `act_hi_procinst` where `ID_` like ? or `PROC_INST_ID_` like ? or `PROC_DEF_ID_` like ? or `START_TIME_` like ? or `END_TIME_` like ? or `DURATION ▶"
>       "bindings" => array:10 [▼
>         0 => "%$searchValue%"
>         1 => "%$searchValue%"
>         2 => "%$searchValue%"
>         3 => "%$searchValue%"
>         4 => "%$searchValue%"
>         5 => "%$searchValue%"
>         6 => "%$searchValue%"
>         7 => "%$searchValue%"
>         8 => "%$searchValue%"
>         9 => "%$searchValue%"
>       ]
>       "time" => 4.0
>     ]
>   ]

how I can fix it? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: re-check param value: '%$searchValue%'

Comment: @Tomato You need to put the value in double quotes(`"`) or you can concatenate them, as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `where('ID_', 'like', '%$searchValue%')` with `where('ID_', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')` and apply it to all the rest

Comment: it's working! Thank you very much! It's no document for this way.

Comment: Its not specific about document @Tomato. Its a mistake you made with way you attempt to pass the value you need. In your first raw query you used a double quote which allows you to pass a variable that would be resolved to the value it holds, on the query builder you used a single quote string.

Comment: @Tomato yes i had to face the same problem you faced to find out how its should be done. Glad to help please mark as answer as correct if possible